# how to draw a container like puzzle piece

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, widget

I want to create a Container widget like below. Can anybody help?
[image]

Comment: Present what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using `ShapeBorder`,

```dart
class MyCardShape extends ShapeBorder {
  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.zero;

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return getOuterPath(rect, textDirection: textDirection);
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    Path path = Path()..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd;
    const radius = Radius.circular(16);

    final holeGap = rect.height * .15;

    final rrect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(rect,
        bottomLeft: radius,
        bottomRight: radius,
        topLeft: radius,
        topRight: radius);

    final holePath = Path()
      ..addOval(
        Rect.fromCircle(
          center: Offset(rect.left, rect.top + rect.height / 2),
          radius: holeGap,
        ),
      )
      ..addOval(
        Rect.fromCircle(
          center: Offset(rect.right, rect.top + rect.height / 2),
          radius: holeGap,
        ),
      );

    final path1 = path
      ..addPath(holePath, Offset.zero)
      ..addRRect(rrect);

    final result = path1;
    return result;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {}
}
```

[image]

And using with  `ClipRRect` to cover the extra shape, you can choose arcToPoint on paint or different methods.

```dart
class UITest extends StatelessWidget {
  const UITest({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ClipRRect(
            // clipping extra
            child: Container(
              width: 400,
              height: 100,
              clipBehavior: Clip
                  .antiAlias, // not sure why this is not working on shape decoration
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                shape: MyCardShape(),
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, `ShapeBorder` used! :-) btw you don't need that extra `ClipRRect` - it kills the idea of using `ShapeBorder`

Comment: @pskink yes  question reminds me of you. there is one little issue without  clip widget. the shape operation painted outside the container width, cant find any git issue about it.  `clipBehavior` on Container is not working with it.

Comment: instead of adding two ovals add two arcs - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/addArc.html

Comment: Yes, arch works. I was exploring container container<clipBehavior> but cant get it now. Btw which is better among [`custom RenderBox`](https://youtu.be/svb41OLzCDY)  and `ShapeBorder`?

Comment: no, no, no don't touch RenderBoxes, unless you really, really, really have to do that :-)

Comment: btw I created a simple [PolygonBorder](https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312#file-round_polygon-dart-L75) class that can be used directly (without any custom class extending `ShapeBorder`) - see `_PolygonBorder` sample widget on how it can be used